# Bluetooth audio stream to commercial headset

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I would to connect my simple audio player (Arduino + https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11125 ) to a Bluetooth headset you can buy at the market.
How can I do ? Is it possible ?

Comment: surely you just "pair" them as any normal Bluetooth API?!

Comment: get a bluetooth module for your arduino and audio thingy, and pair them.

Comment: Hmm, I would also like to know the answer to this question. I know there's a ton of bluetooth mic/speaker modules but I've never seen the "other end". Is there a module for the *player* end? Or can a bluetooth speaker module be used? Or do I need to implement the whole bluetooth stack on a microcontroller? Or does there exist a pre-made stack for some bluetooth controller IC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at this [module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11678) also on spark fun?

It has an embedded stack you just configure over its serial interface.

> Description: This RN-52 Bluetooth from Roving Network is an audio
>   module that provides a highly integrated solution for delivering high
>   quality stereo audio in a small form factor with little difficulty.
>   This module is perfect for a project involving hands free audio for
>   your car, remote controlling your media center, or streaming 2-channel
>   audio.